# Using double integral to do a single integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I am done with calculus a long time ago but I still like the tricky problems for the integral.  Usually, students study single integral and then double integral. More interestingly, some of the one integral problems are hard to do without using a double integral. For example (comes from my teacher note)  :$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(\ln x)}{\ln(x)} \mathrm dx.$$ My points behind this post are

> - It is good for a student to see uncommon approaches to do an integral.
> - Since this site has a lot of good mathematicians around the world. So, they may put their input.

I will open the floor for the people to write their solution if there is any. For the seek of completeness, I will write an answer separatly by using a double integral technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\ln(x)=-y$ and note that  $\frac{1}{y}=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-xy}\mathrm dx. $ Now, plugging $y$ in the integral above, we have $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(x+1)y} \ \sin(y) \  \mathrm dy \ \ \mathrm dx.$$ By using integration by parts, we have  $$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(x+1)y} \ \sin(y) \  \mathrm dy=\frac{1}{(x+1)^2+1}$$ and then $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x+1)^2+1} \mathrm dx=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{\pi}{4}$$